# Add Delay to PresentViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue, viewcontroller

I was wondering how to add a 1.0 second delay to this segue I have in my code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *homeViewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
[self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I know you can do this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showModalTwo:)withObject:someNumber afterDelay:1.0f];
```

I just dont have this or want to make a function to segue. Any help at all would be great. Thanks!

Comment: do you want to perform segue after delay?? or what?

Comment: Yea - i just want that segue to happen after a delay time. I have a login going so i think once i give it a delay, that will give the login enough time to get the information i need to trasnfer with this segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to add delay for waiting an operation to be done (i.e. the login), instead you can use Grand Central Dispatch

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Background Thread
        // do you login logic here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Main Thread : UI Updates
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *homeViewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
            [self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        });
    });
```

Comment: This is not a good way to implement this delay. If you just want to delay the presentation, use `dispatch_after`.

Comment: Actually he didn't need delay, he need to perform login in background the present the view controller after successful login. If he use dispatch_after with delay he will not be sure that the login is finished or not